# How do I use Tattoo Artist?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

The [Tattoo Artist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2962) feat from Secrets of Magic reads:

> When you select this feat, you gain the formulas for four common magical tattoos of 2nd level or lower

Following this, some tattoos are presented to the reader. **Not a single one** of them meets the above requirement: https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?Category=46

The freshly released "The Grand Bazar" book also adds a few, but again **not one of them** is common *or* level 2.

Am I missing something? How am I supposed to use this feat?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Rules

*Tattoo Artist* is currently important not because of the formulae, but because it's the most expedient route to crafting magic tattoos at all.

[Crafting a magic tattoo](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1496) requires the ability " to craft magic items and have a specialty in tattooing." Previously, you *could* do this by taking both the [Magical Crafting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=812) and [Specialty Crafting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=844) skill feats.

*Tattoo Artist* allows you to craft magical tattoos with a single feat. So you can use *Tattoo Artist* even without being able to take advantage of the free formulae. In fact, it's the optimal route to crafting magic tattoos.

Although there are no formulae that match your needs now, it's possible this is "forward compatible" with future releases. Not that it helps you today.

### Potential GM Advice

At my table we have a player making extensive use of magic tattoos. I treated it like an alchemical creation, letting them pick from the table of alchemical items (subject to a GM sanity check). Although this content has only been out for a month or two, so far this has been balanced at our table. We aren't serious character optimizers though, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 5):

RAW, you start with no formulas (since there are currently no 2nd or 1st level tattoos). However, you can still learn the formulas for other tattoos, per the normal [Formulas](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=250) rules, and the circumstance bonus the feat provides will apply to those.

It's not unreasonable to homebrew some 1st and/or 2nd level tattoos with your GM's permission. Obviously, that's not going to work if you are playing in Pathfinder Society, but there's nothing wrong I can see with taking some [Worn Items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?Category=41) and simply reskinning them to be tattoos.

Answer (score 4):

## The low level tattoos have arrived

Treasure Vault contains some [new, low level tattoos](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?Category=46), some of them are even quite useful.